# Dividir Datepicker en dia mes y año

Tags: php, datepicker

tengo un form con un DatePicker, que me envia por post la fecha completa.

```
       <div class="input-group date form_date" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
              <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly placeholder="Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento">
                           <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
          </div>
```

Por otro lado en el back esta esperando 3 variables distintas, un dia, un mes y un año.

```
  $dia=$_POST(curriculum_vitae[fecha_nacimiento][day]);
  $mes=curriculum_vitae[fecha_nacimiento][month]
  $anio=curriculum_vitae[fecha_nacimiento][year]
```

No puedo cambiar el back, entonces como haría para descomponer lo que manda el datepicker y mandarlo en 3 valores?

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no puedes cambiar el backend y sólo puedes resolverlo en el front, no te queda otra que enviarle exactamente lo que espera el back.
Entonces, lo que puedes hacer son estos pequeños cambios en el `form`:

1) Una función que se ejecute en el evento `submit` del formulario.

2) Agregar unos campos ocultos que contendrán la información tal cual la necesita el backend.

3) Agregar un id al `input` del datepicker para poder tomar su valor directamente.

Resumido, así:

```
<form onsumit="return form_submit()">
   <input type="hidden" id="fn_day"   name="fecha_nacimiento[day]">
   <input type="hidden" id="fn_month" name="fecha_nacimiento[month]">
   <input type="hidden" id="fn_year"  name="fecha_nacimiento[year]">
   ...
   <input id="dp_fn" class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly placeholder="Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento">
   ...
</form>
```

La función `form_submit` lo que hace es tomar el valor del datepicker y repartirlo entre los tres campos ocultos:

```
<script>
function form_submit()
{
    // Suponiendo que el input tenga una fecha en formato DD MM YYYY,
    // separar el valor por los espacios:
    var date = $('#dp_fn').val().split(' ');

    // Asignar cada parte de la fecha al campo oculto correspondiente:
    $('#fn_day').val(date[0]);
    $('#fn_month').val(date[1]);
    $('#fn_year').val(date[2]);

    // Realizar el submit del formulario
    return true;
}
</script>
```

De esta manera, al backend debería llegar:

```
$_POST['fecha_nacimiento']['day']
$_POST['fecha_nacimiento']['month']
$_POST['fecha_nacimiento']['year']
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo recibes por POST te recomiendo darle un name a tu codigo:

```
<div class="input-group date form_date" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
   <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" name="fecha_nacimiento" value="" readonly placeholder="Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
</div>
```

Bastaria con pasarle como parametro el *format* a lo que recibes por POST

```
$fecha= strtotime($_POST[fecha_nacimiento]);//tu variable
$dia = strftime("%d",$fecha);
$mes = strftime("%m",$fecha);
$anio = strftime("%Y",$fecha);

echo "el día es: ".$dia;
echo "el mes es: ".$mes;
echo "el año es: ".$anio;
```

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php): Para convertir tu fecha en formato UNIX

[strftime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php): Formatea la fecha en formato actual

Comment: Gracias Walter! El tema es que no peudo tocar el back!!!

Comment: Ohhh!...bueno, creo que si no puedes tocar el backend si lo veo complicado, ya que la fecha la tienes en un solo input, y en el backend es donde debes recibirlo y formatearlo según necesites. Vere si se me ocurre algo, pero sin tocar el php que lo recibe lo veo complicado

Comment: Podrías crear tres inputs, que envien el día, mes y año por separado.